# How to create a good function order file for link.exe /order

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, linker

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/order-put-functions-in-order?view=msvc-170) describes how you can use the `link.exe /order` option to optimise function layout for a program with a function order file. It gives an example of the format so it would be possible to create a file for a small example (e.g.):

```
main
foo
bar
```

How can a create a good link order file for a large/non-trivial application?

`llvm-profdata` has support for creating an [order](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-profdata.html#profdata-order) file for the ELF `lld` `--symbol-ordering-file` option from a profile of the application. Is there a way to do similar on Windows with `link.exe` and `/order`?